# Create an EWS FindItemsResults instance

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am working on creating a wrapper to emulate Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices and consume Graph Email Messages.

I can't seem to create an empty instance of

```
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FindItemsResults<Items>
```

to populate when I create the Item objects. All of the digging on did on the internet has not yielded a way to do this. Does anyone know if I can do this, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I would have tried the following steps to see what the item is. Sharing the code in Answer, as i failed to see any other way. Let me know if this helps.

```
// Send the request to search the Inbox and get the results.
FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, searchFilter, view);

// Process each item.
foreach (Item myItem in findResults.Items)
{
    if (myItem is EmailMessage)
    {
        Console.WriteLine((myItem as EmailMessage).Subject);
    }

    else if (myItem is MeetingRequest)
    {
        Console.WriteLine((myItem as MeetingRequest).Subject);
    }
    else
    {
        // Else handle other item types.
    }
}
```